# При отправлении ботом сообщения в супергруппу пишет chat not found (400)

Tags: telegram-bot, golang

Когда пытаюсь отправить из бота сообщение в супергруппу метод возвращает ошибку `chat not found (400)`, id чата правильный проверил несколько раз, вообще не понимаю в чем проблема, все должно работать.

```
const GroupChatID = int64(-1001358833668)
func (b *Telegram) handleTextMessage() func(msg *tgapi.Message) {
    return func(msg *tgapi.Message) {
        _, err := b.Send(GroupChatID, fmt.Sprintf("Sender: %s\nMessage:\n%s", msg.Sender.Username, msg.Text))
        if err != nil {
            logs.Eloger.WithFields(logrus.Fields{
                "senderID":   msg.Sender.ID,
                "senderName": msg.Sender.Username,
                "errorSource": "function handleTextMessage",
                "errorCause":  "function b.Send",
            }).Error(err)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

скорее всего вам возвращается ошибка "Bad Request: chat not found", а 400 - это error_code.

Идем в [официальную документацию](https://core.telegram.org/api/errors) и читаем что может вызвать ошибку 400. Мое предположение, что проблема в API_ID или в токене.

> API_ID_INVALID: The api_id/api_hash combination is invalid